# Jekyll Liquid Template: Use Variable of Layout in Page

Tags: html, variables, jekyll, liquid

i have the following files:

**_layouts/twoPointLayout.html**

```
---
layout: documentationLayout
---
{% assign col = site.interfaceServer | where:"neededTopCollectionItem", page.topCollectionItem | sort: "order" %}

<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="{{ col[0].url }}">{{ col[0].title }}</a></li>
  <li class="active">{{ page.title }}</li>
</ol>

<h3>{{ col[0].order }}.{{ page.order }} {{ page.title }}</h3>
{{ content }}
```

**someFile.md**

```
---
title: "Some title"
identifier: hints
order: 3
orderPagination: 24
layout: twoPointLayout
topCollectionItem: xyz
neededTopCollectionItem: xyz_hints
---
{% assign items = site.interfaceServer | where:"topCollectionItem", "xdt-documentation_hints" | sort: "order" %}
{{ page.col[0].order }} // This doesn`t work

{% for item in items %}
  <h4 id="{{ item.identifier }}"><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ col[0].order }}.{{ page.order }}.{{ item.order }} {{ item.title }}</a></h4>
{% endfor %}
```

In the Layout `twoPointLayout.html` there is a variable declaration of `col`. Now i need to use this Variable with the same content in the page `someFile.md`.

I have used `page.col[0].order` to access the variable, but it doesn`t work.

How can I access the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put that variable outside the layout and posts, and then [include](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes) it where you need it:

Create an *include* in `_includes/customdata.html`:

```
{% assign col = site.interfaceServer | where:"neededTopCollectionItem", page.topCollectionItem | sort: "order" %}
```

Then include it in `someFile.md`:

```
{%include customdata.html %}
{{col}}
```

or in the *layout*.